# W-2 contractor loopholes

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction, contractor, form-w-2

I am working as a W-2 contractor, not as a 1099 contractor (i.e., pay quarterly). Are there any **loopholes** or **write-offs** that I should be saving receipts for?

- Driving from location to location, gas, and maintenance.
- Working from home paying for office space, square footage, utilities, etc.
- Meals out for business.

If you can think of more, please let me know.

In other words, I am working as a W-2, but sort of like a sole proprietor. As a 1099 contractor you have the right to deduct all business expenses. As a W-2 contractor, what can I do?

Comment: I believe the home-business (office space in your home) write-off has expired for the 2018 tax year under the new tax plan.

Comment: It's a good question.  I think you're "screwed" as a W2.   Try to go 1099 !  It would be good to know what a W2 can do - maybe someone has a list.

Comment: If you get a W-2, you are an employee, not a contractor. As an employee you can't deduct mileage to/from your place of employment. What makes you thin you're a "contractor"?

Comment: @Fattie Note that as a 1099 contractor you're on the hook for self-employment tax which probably negates any benefit of additional deductions.

Comment: quite true, @DStanley - although you can deduct a hell of a lot of stuff (depending on your line of business)  (and I mean, you generally "get more" on 1099, since they don't have to pay)

Comment: as @DStanley suggests, they question should probably be edited "contractor" to "employee"

Comment: I don't think we should edit the Q, unless the OP can clarify why they stated "contractor" and "w2".  The question having any merit at all really comes down to the understanding there I think.

Comment: I guess there is nothing that can be done.  I need to go to bat on the contract re-up, W-2 - Vacation, Sick, Mileage...  And Health Ins, I am not going there.

Comment: @D Stanley: But if you're working as a contractor, you should be charging at least enough more per hour (or whatever) than an employee wage, in order to cover the cost of self-employment tax.  And the value of other "benefits" employees receive.

Comment: @moojjoo There's a difference between an employee with a contract and an "_independent_ contractor". If you want to go independent you can try that, but make sure you understand the consequences, including taxes, benefits, retirement, etc.

Comment: D Stanley thank you and believe me the first thing I will do is hire ADP to handle business payroll, even if I am the only one on that payroll.  Been there done that.

Answer (score 7):

To be clear, if you are receiving a W-2, you are an employee, not a self-employed contractor.

Before the new tax reform law, it was possible to deduct unreimbursed employee expenses. These were expenses that you incurred as part of your job that your employer did not reimburse you for. Expenses eligible for deduction included tools and supplies, mileage (beyond the normal daily commute), home office expenses, etc. There were two big caveats to deducting these expenses:

- The deduction was part of the itemized deductions. If you took the standard deduction, you could not deduct these.
- You could only deduct expenses that were greater than 2% of your Adjusted Gross Income.

However, with the [Tax Cuts and Jobs Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tax_Cuts_and_Jobs_Act_of_2017), this deduction has been eliminated beginning in 2018. In order to pay for these expenses tax free, you must be reimbursed by your employer. (Reimbursements are not considered taxable income.)

Answer (score -3):

Speaking of work expenses, they are non-taxable as reimbursements, here is a comprehensive article on what are they exactly: https://smallbusiness.chron.com/taxes-work-expenses-w2-employees-22603.html

Comment: Welcome to Money.SE.  Unfortunately, your answer doesn't really fit the question above, as the OP is not being reimbursed by his employer for these expenses.  In addition, the article that you posted is out of date and does not take into account the tax reform changes in 2018, specifically the elimination of the unreimbused job expense deduction.